# proving that if $a, b$ are random non-zero integers, then $D$ is non-empty

Tags: probability, proof-writing

> Suppose a, b are two randomly chosen non-zero integers. Then the set $D = \{ax+by : x,y 
> ∈ \mathbb{Z}, ax+by>0\}$ is non-empty.

My lecturer wrote this up in my notes, saying that this is a true statement without actually proving it. I cannot understand why it's true. Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|a|+|b|>0$ so at least one among these $4$ numbers belongs to $D$:
$$
a+b,a-b,-a+b,-a-b.
$$

Comment: i don't get it why one of them must belong to D ?

Comment: Because one of those 4 numbers equals $|a|+|b|>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $x=a\in\mathbb Z$ and $y=b\in\mathbb Z$ gives: $$ax+by=a^2+b^2>0$$ and consequently $ax+by\in D$.

In fact the condition $a\neq0\wedge b\neq0$ can be replaced by the weaker $a\neq0\vee b\neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider $x$ and $y$ to be $+1$ or $-1$.
Then there are three cases:

1. $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $1\cdot a+1\cdot b>0$ so $a+b\in D$
2. One of $a,b$ is positive, the other one negative, say $a<0,b>0$. Then $-1\cdot a+1\cdot b>0$ so $-a+b\in D$
3. Both $a$ and $b$ are negative, then $-a-b\in D$

This should clarify that, whatever case you look at, there always is something in $D$, so $D$ is non-empty